# Recursive and non-recursive property: Are these assertions equal?

Tags: properties, system-verilog, verification, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

Consider the following specification:

```
"interrupt must hold until interrupt ack is received"
```

[image]

Are these assertions equal and corresponding to the specification?

1- First assertion (using a recursive property):

```
property intr_hold(intr, intrAck);
   intrAck or (intr and (1'b1 |=> intr_hold(intr, intrAck)));
endproperty 

assert property @(posedge clk) $rose(intr) |=> intr_hold(intr, intrAck);
```

2- Second assertion (using a non-recursive property):

```
assert property @(posedge clk) intr |=> intr or past(intrAck);
```

*Thank you*

Comment: The *non-recursive assertion* will pass if it finds `intr` and `intrAck` **on the same clock** (it checks for `intr` in one clock and on the next clock `$past(intrAck)` which will be same clock), while the *recursive assertion* will check for `intrAck` **from the next clock** only. Can the `intrAck` be high at same clock when `intr` arrives? If that is the case, then I think the non-recursive assertion should work fine for the current scenario.

Comment: As an alternative, one can give a try to this property as well: `@(posedge clk) intr |=> strong(##[0:$] intr or intrAck);` (modify single/double implication as per requirement).

Comment: Just curious. Why the second is a falling case? it fits the requirement as well.

Comment: @Serge the second is not a falling case. It's a "failing" case.

Comment: sorry, typo, i meant fa_i_ling. So, why it was *failing*?

Comment: @Serge The non-recursive case works fine for current scenario if `intr` and `intrAck` are allowed to set in same clock pulse. As a cleaner alternate to non-recursive property, one can try property that I showed (by making adjustments as per spec).

Comment: @sharvil111 The property you showed states that there is cycle sometime in the future where `intr` is high, until an occurrence of `intrAck`, but it doesn't require `intr` to stay high until then.

Comment: @TudorTimi Agree... I perceived that it would check for `intr` and then check that at any succeeding clock either `intr` of `intrAck` should be high.

Answer (score 0):

The first property doesn't accept cycles where both `intr` and `intrAck` are low. In such a cycle the first part of the `or` fails so the second part has to be evaluated. This part can't pass, because the first part of the `and` fails and thus the conjunction fails. The entire property fails.

Even if we ignore such cycles, the first assertion doesn't catch the failing case.

Let's analyze your example from when the `intr` signal goes high.

- on the first cycle `intrAck` fails, but the second part of the `or` starts matching. `intr` passes and the implication's antecendent matches and triggers the recursive evaluation on the next cycle
- on the second cycle, a new evaluation of the property starts and the same thing repeats. There is still the evaluation of the consequent from the previous cycle (the recursive evaluation). For this one, another recursive evaluation will get scheduled. Now two evaluations of the property are "active".
- on the third cycle `intrAck` passes and the new property attempt passes. The two previously scheduled property evaluations also pass, because `intrAck` is high and state that the property evaluations started at cycles 1 and 2 also pass.

The non-recursive form is fine.

From a simulation efficiency point of view, even if the recursive form were re-written somehow to conform to the specification, it would be worse. This is because there are many pending property evaluations. The property evaluation that started on cycle 1 was still "alive" until cycle 3. The property evaluation that started on cycle 2 was also still alive until cycle 3, so in cycle 2 there were  If there were a forth cycle needed to determine a pass/fail, there would be a third pending evaluation. A tool might be able to implement this more efficiently by ignoring previous evaluations once a new one of the same property was started (as fails will anyway get signaled), but simulators usually show when a finished property evaluation started for debug purposes and this gets more complicated to implement if "old" evaluations are thrown away and replaced by recursive ones.

Comment: According to the specification, the assertion is not needed to accept cycles when `intr` and `intrAck` are 0. It is only needed to check whether 'intr' is 1 as long as intrAck is not 1. I am agree that the recursive property has too much overhead. I just wanted to know whether it is correct or not. But, as @sharvil111 said, recursive property doesn't verify when intrAck and intr are 1 at same clock. So, it's incorrect.